# How to put an item value to an ActionLink (MVC3 Grid)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I just need to put the item value to `ActionLink`.

What I have is the following:

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Report", "CombinedData", new { id = item.ChainID })),
grid.Column("OwnerName", "Owner"),
```

So I need instead of `"Report"` put the `"OwnerName"` to see the **Owner** there to exclude 1 extra line (`grid.Column("OwnerName", "Owner"),`)

How is it possible to do?

Thank you!

Comment: @Xander Hmm I guess it is a standard MVC3 Grid

Comment: @Xander I just use  @grid.GetHtml( and etc... no any special DLLs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(
    (string)item.OwnerName, 
    "CombinedData", 
    new { id = item.ChainID }
))
```

Be careful because the ActionLink helper doesn't accept null and Empty strings as first argument. So if potentially you could have null or Empty `OwnerName` properties on your model you will have to test for this condition and put some generic, non-empty name. Or simply add a calculated field on your view model that will do this job:

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(
    (string)item.FormattedOwnerName, 
    "CombinedData", 
    new { id = item.ChainID }
))
```